# Spark MLib Matrix Multiplication

Tags: scala, matrix, machine-learning, apache-spark

I tried the following code in Spark console

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Matrix, Matrices, DenseMatrix}

val dm: DenseMatrix = new DenseMatrix(3, 2, Array(1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0))

val md: DenseMatrix = new DenseMatrix(2, 3, Array(1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0))

dm.multiply(md) //this line throws an error
```

The error message that i get is:

```
error: value multiply is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix
```

meanwhile i can call `dm.toString`, `dm.numRows` and `dm.numCols` i get results but when i call `dm.multiply`, it throws an error.

what am i doing wrong??

Comment: Version issue? What version of Spark are you using? multiply certainly seems to be present in the latest ScalaDoc...

Comment: am using Spark version 1.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured out that multiply() is not supported on v1.1.0

[Spark v1.1.0](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseMatrix)

fixed this by upgrading to v1.2.0